# Отсутствие переводов при задании фильтрации по метке пользовательского фильтра

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, локализация, метки, фильтрация-вопросов

При фильтрации вопросов можно их фильтровать по метке у вопроса, но меня немного смущает `or`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это на МЕТЕ, на основном сайте так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

конечно на основном сайте оно гармонично смотрится рядом с названием меток, но наверное тут должно быть что-то типа `или`

Comment: А почему вы [этот вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/11477/timeline) так не хотите оставить в списке живых? Ведь дубликаты это вовсе не что-то плохое. Дубликаты позволяют находить поиском то, что без них было бы сложно найти.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, восстановил :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эти "or" являются частью запроса и относятся больше к языку запроса, а не просто английскому языку. Скорее всего это исправляться не будет по той же самой причине, по которой отклонили мой запрос на MSE [Localization for multitagged RSS feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292313/339911) тоже описывающий ситуацию с метками.

Comment: я понял, думал что ошибка которую не заметили) спасибо большое за информацию)

Comment: @Andrew вообще, можно было бы и доработать, чтобы смотрелось консистентно на неангло-сайтах тоже. Но это надо много всего с метками переработать. Запретить метки "и", "или", "не" по аналогии с запретом для "and", "or", "not" и т.д.

Comment: ну если с нашей стороны это можно как-то сделать, то готов помочь в пределах своих сил, я просто не очень знаю что кто может делать на сайтах сети, поэтому могу порой говорить глупые вещи)

Comment: @Andrew всё, что можно делать, минуя разработчиков SO, это править переводы. Сейчас доступные через ru.traducir.win. Если строка, видимая пользователю, отсутствует в словаре (база для переводов), то дальше надо уже привлекать SOтрудников.

Comment: я просто не очень понял вот эту строку `Но это надо много всего с метками переработать. Запретить метки "и", "или", "не" по аналогии с запретом для "and", "or", "not" и т.д` - имеется ввиду описание меток или что-то другое? и поэтому я спросил от кого это можно сделать)

Comment: @Andrew это моё видение/предположение того, что придётся делать SOтрудникам, если взяться за работу по локализации "or" -> "или" и т.д. в метках.

Comment: я понял, я допускаю что может у SOтрудников есть много тасков которые более горящие чем какая-то локализация)

Comment: @Andrew это точно так и есть.